# What is this weird black and white stuff on my chickpeas?

Tags: pressure-cooker, chickpeas

[image: chickpea with white and black stuff on it]

I soaked my chickpeas for 24 hours and just cooked them in my pressure cooker. I added salt and pepper before cooking. I just tasted one and it was perfect. Then I drained them and saw that lots of them have this weird white and black stuff on them. Sorry the picture isn't super clear.

What do you think it is and it is safe to eat?

Comment: Presumably pepper flakes bloated with cooking water & stuck to chickpea guts... Personally, I save the seasoning for after cooking, and I've never seen this, so that's my guess.

Comment: Maybe they were sprouting and the sprout cooked to mush? BTW I wouldn't eat this.

Comment: Ec and Jan - thanks for your replies. 

Dramatic conclusion - I smelled and tasted the "stuff" last night and it was odorless and and flavorless.  I wound up eating some this morning and I am still alive. I think the black stuff is pepper and the white stuff is probably foam.